# Why is there a random jump in this Jquery animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2NFNS/

html:

```
<div id = 'text'>Text</div>
```

js:

```
$('#text').on('click', function() {
    $('#text').animate({'top':'-300px'}, 3000);
});
```

css:

```
#text {
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(25% + 125px);
    left:calc(50% - 285px);

    text-align: left;
    height:50px;
    width:500px;
    background:red;
    color:#aaa;
}
```

Why does it jump to the top, and then animate? Also, why doesn't the text show up?

Comment: Works fine for me. The text might not show up because you've resized your window too much.

Comment: I don't see a jump. and i see the text

Comment: Step away, spin 3 times, jump on your right foot, go back to the keyboard and hit control-F5.   Just kidding.  Thought I would try to lighten things up on what is probably a nightmare for you.  Hope you find the solution.

Comment: It doesn't work for me in Safari.

Comment: using css3 transitions is fast and easy, but it's not a cross browser solution, there are still lots of projects in the world need to support IE 6,7,8 which is unfortunate. I thought for the morden browser, undoutbly using css3 transtions, using javascript to fallback if css3 transtions is not supported. mainly (IE 6,7,8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you use CSS3 transitions.

CSS

```
#text {
    position:absolute;
    top:calc(25% + 125px);
    left:calc(50% - 285px);

    text-align: left;
    height:50px;
    width:500px;
    background:red;
    color:#aaa;
    -webkit-transition:all 3.0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 3.0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 3.0s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 3.0s ease-in-out; 
}
```

JS

```
$('#text').on('click', function() {
    $('#text').css('top','-300px');
});
```

[You can see the example here](http://jsfiddle.net/NEOLPAR/Ars8N/1/)